# shortest path in Directed graph in networkx

Tags: python, numpy, networkx, shortest-path

I want to use a defined graph (Org_graph) and find shortest paths between some nodes. Org_graph is a graph like this type:

```
Org_graph =[[0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
          [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
          [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
          [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],      
          [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0],
          [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
          [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
         ]
```

So at the first I have converted it to a networkx graph and then use it's function to find shortest paths. In converting I am using "numpy" and "from_numpy_matrix()" program.

```
Org_graph2 =np.matrix(Org_graph) 

G=nx.DiGraph()
G=nx.from_numpy_matrix(Org_graph2)

#X is source node
#Y is destination node
print (nx.shortest_path(G,X,Y)
```

My problem is that, Org_graph is a directed graph but when I am using nx.shortest_path(G,X,Y), it returns paths which is for a undirected graph.

Is it correct way to find shortest path from this graph? and where is wrong in my implementation ?

Comment: Have you tried: `G = nx.from_numpy_matrix(Org_graph2, create_using=nx.DiGraph)` ? (just going by: https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/generated/networkx.convert_matrix.from_numpy_matrix.html)

Comment: `G = nx.DiGraph()` binds the name `G` to an empty digraph, you then rebind it to an undirected one from the result of `nx.from_numpy_matrix...`

Comment: @JonClements thank you. it works. but really is there difference between create "DiGraph" then using "numpy" convert and numpy convert with create_using attribute ?!!.

Comment: Yes... as I said... creating a variable and then creating it again doesn't alter the existing one. You're creating one G, then creating another G and the old one goes away... you're not changing the first `G` anywhere... Think of it as doing `a = 1` then immediately after `a = 2`...

Comment: @JonClements thanks. you answered my question in comment

Comment: Feel free to self answer it so it may be useful to others in future (if it's not already somewhere on the site...)